# Numerical integration in one variable, of a multivariable interpolation function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, interpolation, variable-definitions

I create the following set of data:

```
newmatrix = Flatten[Table[{t, v, new[t, v]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}, {v, 0, 1, 
0.01}], 1]
```

where

```
new[t_, v_] = t^2 + v^2
```

Then I defined a function that interpolate the previous data set:

```
newfun = Interpolation[newmatrix, Method -> "Hermite"]
```

I can plot it:

[image]

Now I need to integrate the interpolation function in one of the two variables like:

```
NIntegrate[newfun[t, v], {t, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

but it doesen't work.

The error code is:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand <<1>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.785398}}.
```

Where is my error ?

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Comment: You need to give a numerical value for `v`.  Try  `newfun[1, v]` and you'll why.

Comment: Where I have to try to use newfun[1,v]?

Comment: I mean just type `newfun[1, v]` before you call `NIntegrate` you'll see the problem. You need to have a numerical value for `v` inside NIntegrate call.

Comment: Basically you saying that I have to create another set of data with some numerical evaluation of the previously integral for some values of v, and then I can create another interpolation function in the variable v?

Comment: I need to have a new function in the only variable v.

Comment: No I mean, you need to use something like `NIntegrate[newfun[t, v], {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]` so that both `t` and `v` have numerical values. Or do `NIntegrate[newfun[t, 99], {t, 0, 1}]` or something. `NIntegrate` basically will not work otherwise.

Comment: I understand it, but it is not what I need...

Comment: If you are looking for a function of $v$, maybe this is what you want:  `g[v_] = Integrate[newfun[t, v], {t, 0, 1} ;  Plot[g[v], {v, 0, 1}]]` ?

Comment: Yeah it works only for the case where the  function is an integrating analitically function ,like newfun[t,v]. But I need also the case of non-analitically integrating function.

Comment: `nint[v_] := NIntegrate[newfun[t, v], {t, 0, 1}]; Plot[nint[v], {v, 0, 1}] `

Comment: Yes, but if now I try to integrate nint[v] numerically, it gives me errors

Comment: Ok, if you later want integrate, define nint to get only integrated if v is  ?NumericQ  `nint[v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[newfun[t, v], {t, 0, 1}]; NIntegrate[nint[v], {v, 0, 1}] `

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) to do your partial integration:

```
g = Derivative[-1, 0][newfun];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[g[1, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that using [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) in this way implies that the lower limit of integration is at the boundary of the interpolation domain.

Comment: It is what I need, clear! Thanks you! But now I have another question: I noticed with the method "Hermite" I can plot 3-dimensionally the new function g, but i can't with the method "Spline".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the use of Derivative and why you plot g[1,x], what do you mean with the "one" in first argument of the new 'g' function?

Comment: `Derivative[-1, 0][newfun]` means integrate over the first variable starting from the beginning of the domain, in this case integrating starting at `t = 0`. `g[1, x]` means integrate up to `t = 1`.

Comment: I can plot 3-dimensionally the new 'g[x,y]' function, so I can't understand why 'Derivative' implies a lower limit of integration

Comment: `g[x, y]` means integrate your interpolating function from `t = 0` to `t = x`. You can choose `x` to be any value in the domain of the interpolating function.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. It is a way that lives between numeric and analitic integration. Sorry for disturbance, but I'm new in Mathematica. Another quest: how can I underline  with gray some part of comments ? Thanks!